# I can´t transform this if statement into an if/elseif one. It won´t work. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: php, drupal, if-statement

I´m experimenting with if/elseif, and can´t understand why it won´t work this in a Drupal 6 template.

This code works:

```
<?php
    if ((arg(0) == 'node') && (arg(1) == 'add') || (arg(1) == 'edit')){
    $node = node_load(array('nid' => arg(1)));
    print '<h2>' .  $title . '</h2>';   }
?>
```

In case I´m in node/add/whatever or node/nid/edit it shows the title variable wrapped into h2´s.
Now, I want to show something slightly different in case node/add and node/edit.
So, I´ve tried this:

```
<?php
if ((arg(0) == 'node') && (arg(1) == 'edit')) {
    $node = node_load(array('nid' => arg(1)));
    print '<h3>' .  $title . '</h3>';
} elseif ((arg(0) == 'node') && (arg(1) == 'add')) {
    $node = node_load(array('nid' => arg(1)));
    print '<h2>' .  $title . '</h2>';   }
} else {
    echo ""; //it shows nothing
}
?>
```

And it won´t work (won´t show anything).
So, I´ve tried this:

```
<?php
    if ((arg(0) == 'node') && (arg(1) == 'add')){
    $node = node_load(array('nid' => arg(1)));
    print '<h2>' .  $title . '</h2>';   }
?>
<?php
    if ((arg(0) == 'node') && (arg(1) == 'edit')){
    $node = node_load(array('nid' => arg(1)));
    print '<h3>' .  $title . '</h3>';
    }
?>
```

And in this case, it works only with node/add, but completely ignores node/edit.

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks for your advice!

Comment: Have you tried echo arg(0); echo arg(1); before the if statement to see what the values are?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path for a node edit page is `node/[nid]/edit`...you need to use `arg(2)` instead:

```
if ((arg(0) == 'node') && is_numeric(arg(1)) && (arg(2) == 'edit')){
```